# Do uncalibrated "probability" predictions satisfy Kolmogorov's axioms?

Tags: machine-learning, probability, classification, calibration, kolmogorov-axioms

Let's say we have some binary variable of interest and fit a model to predict the probability of the two classes, say a logistic regression or a "classification" neural network. This model gives us predictions in the interval $[0, 1]$.

Must these predictions satisfy the Kolmogorov probability axioms, even if these predictions lack calibration?

We definitely get that the values are non-negative, and I think having an upper bound $1$ gives us unit measure (but I am not as confident about this). For $\sigma$-additivity, I have no idea.

Comment: The Kolmogoroff axioms are formal properties, calibration is not part of the axioms.

Comment: So the values satisfy the three axioms just by being in the interval $[0,1]?$ @kjetilbhalvorsen

Comment: Well, there are some other properties ... the logistic regression model you mention is based on the binomial distribution. Estimated probabilities you can calculate from the model is binomial probabilities, so you only need to check if the binomial distribution is consistent with Kolmogoroff!

Comment: Sigma additivity of what space, specifically?  The sample space seems to be $\{0,1\}$ with the discrete measure but surely you don't have any questions about additivity (much less sigma additivity) in that space!

Comment: Does the model predict "probability" p for class 1 and 1-p for class 2? Or p1 for class 1 and p2 for class 2? The latter would not imply unit measure unless p1+p2 happened to be 1.

Comment: @NuclearHoagie I’m considering the case of mutually exclusive categories, so a prediction of $p$ for one category implies a prediction of $1-p$ for the other.

Comment: So the Kolmogorov axioms are satisfied, since $p\ge 0$, $1-p\ge 0$ and $p+(1-p)=1$

Comment: It occurs to me that calibration is only really applicable as a tool for evaluating probabilistic predictions - there is no sense of calibration for non-probability scores on arbitrary scales. If the predictions are not probabilities, I don't really see how one can evaluate calibration in the first place. If you can even evaluate a model's calibration, whether it is calibrated or not, it implies the model is producing probabilities (otherwise you are mis-applying calibration).

Comment: @NuclearHoagie That makes it sound like the requirement is just that the values be in the $[0,1]$ interval. That seems to be the gist of the answer/comments by Kjetil, and perhaps that is what is meant by saying the Kolmogorov axioms are just formal properties.

Answer (score 3):

Making comments into an answer:

1. The Kolmogorov axioms are formal properties, calibration is not part of the axioms.
2. The logistic regression model you mention is based on the binomial distribution. Estimated probabilities you can calculate from the model is binomial probabilities, so you only need to check if the binomial distribution is consistent with Kolmogorov!

Comment: For the second point, is all you mean that $p,1-p\in[0,1]$, $p +(1-p)=1$, and $P(\{0\}\cup\{1\})=1=p+(1-p)?$

Comment: I guess I mean that the binomial distribution is developed using theory based on the axioms, so how could it not be consistent with the axioms?

Comment: That makes sense. However, something is still troubling about this. Is the point of checking the Kolmogorov axioms that we check them for each Bernoulli distribution with fitted/predicted probability parameter $\hat p_i$, rather than checking across all predictions? Why?

Comment: The point is maybe that no checking needs to be done, as it is already done!

Comment: I agree that it is done if we only care about each individual Bernoulli distribution. However, why don’t we care about the entire collection of predictions?

Comment: @Dave: As long as independence is assumed, there is no difference