# Can a ML classifier's prediction be understood as a probability?

Tags: machine-learning, probability, classification, conditional-probability, scikit-learn

When predicting classes with a machine learning classifier, such as scikit-learn's `DecisionTreeClassifier` or `KNeighborsClassifier` the predictions work by calling `predict_proba()`, which predicts the probability for an input to be in each class. Calling the classifiers's `predict()` simply chooses the class with the highest probability.

How does the `predict_proba()` relate to probility theory? Can I say the classifier's output is the probability that the sample is of class $\mathcal C_k$ given an input vector $\mathbf x_i$, such that `predict_proba()` $\Leftrightarrow p(\mathcal C_k|\mathbf x_i)$?

My goal is to use this conditional probability together with my prior knowledge of the class distribution by applying Bayes' theorem.

Comment: people do this all the time, but one should be cautious because; see e.g. https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/309642/why-is-softmax-output-not-a-good-uncertainty-measure-for-deep-learning-models

Comment: A *probability* satisfies the Kologorov axioms, which is not that hard to demonstrate for a classifier prediction. I think the (unstated) concern that you have is about the *trustworthiness* or *precision* of that estimate. Often, when a classifier tells me "This object is Class 1 with probability 1.0," I feel a certain amount of skepticism; some of the reasons are outlined in John Madden's link.

Comment: The model's output is an *estimate* of this probability. As explained by Dave's answer, this estimate can be good or bad.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That would be desirable, but it is not guaranteed to make as much sense as we might like.

First, you could make an argument that any predicted $p(\mathcal C_k|\mathbf x_i)\in[0,1]$ is a probability in the sense that it can define a binomial or multinomial distribution parameter that governs how often a particular event occurs; [the Kolmogorov axioms are satisfied](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/626312/247274). However, in order to assert $p(\mathcal C_k|\mathbf x_i)$ as a probability, it would be nice for it to be the case that, when you assert event $\mathcal C_k$ to happen with probability $p$, then $\mathcal C_k$ really does happen $p\times100\%$ of the time.

This gets into the assessment of model [calibration](/questions/tagged/calibration): if the predicted probabilities align with the reality of how often a particular category occurs. For instance, if you keep predicting event $\mathcal C_k$ to happen with a probability above $0.9$ and only observe $\mathcal C_k$ happening in $60\%$ of those instances, your predictions lack calibration.

Many machine learning models lack calibration, and this leads to the caution Madden mentions in the comments. Calibrating their predictions is an open problem. See, for instance [Guo et al (ICML 2017)](http://proceedings.mlr.press/v70/guo17a/guo17a.pdf) and my [question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/552533/247274) about it.

**REFERENCES**

[Guo, Chuan, et al. "On calibration of modern neural networks." International Conference on Machine Learning. PMLR, 2017.](http://proceedings.mlr.press/v70/guo17a/guo17a.pdf)